Show $A:=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{2n+1}, \frac{1}{2n}]$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ is locally compact
I have been trying to show that the set $A:=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{2n+1}, \frac{1}{2n}]$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ is locally compact, and $\mathbb{R}\setminus A$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ is not locally compact.
Using the definition in Munkres, a topological space $X$ is locally compact if for every $x\in X$, there exist an open subset $U$ of $X$ and a compact subspace $C$ of $X$ such that $x\in U \subset C$.
So to show $A$ is locally compact, take any element $a\in A$. Then, $a\in(\frac{1}{2k+1}, \frac{1}{2k}]$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$. The set $(\frac{1}{2k+1}, \frac{1}{2k}]$ is open in $A$ since $(\frac{1}{2k+1}, \frac{1}{2k}]=A \cap (\frac{1}{2k+1}, p)$ where $p$ is any number in $(\frac{1}{2k}, \frac{1}{2k-1})$, and $(\frac{1}{2k+1}, p)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$. Now, is this $(\frac{1}{2k+1}, \frac{1}{2k}]$ contained in any compact subspace of $A$? I am not sure how compact subspaces of $A$ look like.
To show $\mathbb{R}\setminus A$ is not locally compact, I think that $0\in\mathbb{R}\setminus A$ is a problematic point. But I am not sure how to show there is no open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}\setminus A$ and a compact subspace $C$ of $\mathbb{R}\setminus A$ such that $0\in U \subset C$.

$A\cong\Bbb N\times(0,1]$ and both factors are locally compact. $\forall a\in(0,1]$, $[a/2,1]$ is a compact neighborhood of $a$ in $(0,1]$.

In $\Bbb R\setminus A$, any neighborhood of $0$ contains intervals of the form $(\frac1{2k},\frac1{2k-1}]$, which are closed and non-compact.

Whenever you want to check if a space is locally compact, first try to make sure it is Hausdorff:

If a topological space $X$ is Hausdorff, then $X$ is locally compact
if, and only if for all for all $x\in X$ and for all open sets
$U$ such that $x\in U$, there exists some open subset $V\subset U$
such that $x\in V$, $\text{Cl}(V)\subset U$ and $\text{Cl}(V)$ is compact in $X$.

This is Theorem 29.2 from Munkres. Notice that if we are given a base for the topology of $X$, it only suffices to check the existence of such $V$ when $U$ is a basic open subset of $X$ containing $x$.
Now, let's proceed to prove that the given space $A$ is locally compact.
First, notice that $A$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R$ with its usual topology, which is a Hausdorff topological space, and therefore, $A$ is Hausdorff (Theorem 17.11 from Munkres). Now, let $x\in A$; then there exists some $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $x\in(1/(2n+1),1/(2n)]$. Let's divide our discussion into two cases:

$x=1/2n$. Then all basic open and connected sets of $A$ that contain $x$ are of the form $U=(a,x]$, where $1/(2n+1)\leq a$. Then it is clear that the neighbourhood $V=((x+a)/2,x]$ is open, contains $x$, its closure is contained in $U$ and it is compact in $A$ (notice that $(x+a)/2$ is nothing but the midpoint between $a$ and $x$).

If $x\not=1/2n$, then all basic open neighbourhoods of $x$ in $A$ that are connected are of the form $(a,b)$ or $(a,1/(2n)]$ where $1/(2n+1)\leq a<x$, $x<b<1/(2n)$. In either case, we can construct a $V$ satisfying the required properties by considering the open interval whose extremes are the midpoint between $a$ and $x$ and $x$ and $b$ in the first case, and the semi-open interval whose extremes are the midpoint of $a$ and $x$ and $1/2n$, in the other case.


This proves that $A$ is locally compact.
